# Why would the Temple turn to a House of Prayer?

Tags: tefilla, beis-hamikdash, korban, nevua-prophecy

> "וַהֲבִיאוֹתִים אֶל־הַר קָדְשִׁי **וְשִׂמַּחְתִּים בְּבֵית תְּפִלָּתִי**
> עוֹלֹתֵיהֶם וְזִבְחֵיהֶם לְרָצוֹן עַל־מִזְבְּחִי,
> כִּי בֵיתִי **בֵּית־תְּפִלָּה יִקָּרֵא** לְכָל־הָעַמִּים׃"
> "I will bring them to My sacred mount
> And let them rejoice in My **house of prayer**.
> Their burnt offerings and sacrifices
> Shall be welcome on My altar;
> For My House **shall be called A house of prayer** for all peoples." [Isaiah.56.7](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.56.7?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=Ibn%20Ezra&lang2=en)

The prophet calls the Temple " the House of prayer". That stumbles me, as the sages instituted the prayer *as an alternative* for Templaic sacrifices, as the Talmud says ([Berakhot.26b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.26b.4?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)): "רַבִּי יְהוֹשֻׁעַ בֶּן לֵוִי אָמַר: תְּפִלּוֹת כְּנֶגֶד תְּמִידִין תִּקְּנוּם", since both are called "עבודה" which God commands us on.

IIRC, there were no established *public* prayers (as opposed to blessings or sanctifications) recited in the Temple, neither the first nor the second.

Why would the prophet call the Temple "the house of prayer" and if the sacrifices will be reestablished, why would it be called so for all nations?

Comment: The concept of prayer existed before the end of the Temple, as we find the forefathers prayed.

Comment: See the Mishna, masechets Yoma and Rosh Hashanah, there were at least prayers in the Beit haMikdash on those holidays

Comment: I've heard it suggested that this was necessary to emphasize that this Temple would be different from temples for false gods found worldwide- first and foremost it would be a place of prayer, and only second for sacrifices. Something interesting that perhaps some here would not like hearing is that in the ancient city of Ugarit, a text was found telling the story of some Canaanite gods wanting to build a temple/palace for Baal. The structure is called in the story a "בית ארזים", which is how David referred to the Temple.

Comment: The view I mentioned above goes on to say that Shlomo intended to argue against the idolatrous view of a temple literally housing a god - hence, sacrifices - food for the gods - but was rather a place where people of all walks of life could come and pray to God.

Comment: @JoshK Please elaborate.

Comment: was the shir sung by the levi'im a form of prayer?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Vessels_of_the_Sanctuary_and_Those_who_Serve_Therein.6?lang=he

Comment: תְּפִלּוֹת כְּנֶגֶד תְּמִידִין תִּקְּנוּם doesn't mean "as an alternate" but rather "as an analogue" or something like that. We get our prayer times and counts from the Temple, not the concept of prayer.

Comment: @JoelK Even better https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.53a.10 and of course https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Tamid.5.1

Comment: Seeing as the verse you quote speaks of burnt offerings and sacrifices, I would assume that being in the Temple and bringing a sacrifice would be an auspicious occasion to offer up an (informal) prayer. Informal prayer, such as Tefilat Channah in I Samuel 1:9, has been around forever and is a natural expression of faith, it does not require a rabbinic enactment. As for Gentiles and sacrifices, Rambam rules that Gentiles may offer burnt offerings in the Temple. Beyond that, in Messianic times it's quite possible that they will be able to offer the full spectrum of korbanos ומלאה הארץ דעה את ה'.

Comment: Chana went to the Bais Hamikdash and prayed there for a son. Many of our laws of prayer are learned from that incident.

Comment: "_IIRC, there were no established **public** prayers (as opposed to blessings or sanctifications) recited in the Temple, neither the first nor the second_". The verse doesn't talk about _public_ prayer either, so I don't see the problem. A _house of prayer_ can just mean a house where an individual can go and speak/pray to God, when he desires/needs to, and have better expectation of being answered (without having to do so with others, or when others do).

Answer (score 1):

the gemara in megilla 18a
explains the seder in smhone esre
as follows …..
The posuk says והביאותים אל וכו..

1. את צמח arrival of ben david —“har kodshee”
2. שמעtefilla —- “bbais tefilosi”
3. רצה avoda / korbonos -“al mizbichee”

It seems that when moshiach comes the temple needs to become a bais tefilla with or without sacrifices.   Only then can the korbanos begin.
Once the era of korbanos begin maybe “jews” will stop calling it Bais Tefilla and only the nations will call it that way. Hence the posuk ends with כי ביתי ……יקרא לכל העמים

until then we have tefilla in the “place” of korbanos

Comment: Please edit to include the source of the possuk   והביאותים אל הר קדשי ושמחתים בבית תפלתי עולתיהם וזבחיהם לרצון על מזבחי כי ביתי בית תפלה יקרא לכל העמים

Comment: please read this explanation of the meaning of the house of hashem. https://btya.org/mishkan-meaning-of-a-bayis-lashem/

Answer (score 1):

The Temple was always meant to be a place of prayer, as we see from Solomon's dedication speech for the first Temple (Kings I Ch. 8):

> [Therefore] turn to the prayer of Your servant, and to his plea, Adonoy, my God; to listen to the song and to the prayer that Your servant prays before You this day:
> 29That Your eyes be open toward this Beis Hamikdosh night and day, to the place of which You said, ‘My Name will be there; to listen to the prayer that Your servant will pray at this place.
> 30And listen to the plea of Your servant, and of Your people, Yisroel, that they will pray toward this place; and You will listen in the place of Your dwelling, in the heavens, and You will listen and forgive.
> 31Should a person sin against his fellow man, and is liable that a curse be upon him, and the curse comes before Your Altar, in this House;
> 32May You listen from the heavens, and act and judge Your servants, to condemn the wicked one, to set his [evil] way upon his head; and to justify the righteous one, to give him according to his righteousness.
> 33When Your people, Yisroel are defeated by an enemy because they sinned against You; and they turn to You and praise Your Name, and pray and beseech You in this Beis Hamikdosh.
> 34May You listen from the heavens, and forgive the sin of Your people, Yisroel; and return them to the land that You gave to their fathers.
> 35When the heavens are closed off and there is no rain, because they sinned against You; and they pray toward this place and praise Your Name, and repent of their sins, for You to answer them.
> 36May You listen from the heavenss and forgive the sin of Your servants and Your people, Yisroel, for You will teach them the right way so they will walk in it; and give rain on Your land that You gave to Your people for an inheritance.
> 37Should there be a famine in the land, or should there be a plague, or if the crops be endangered by wind or rot, locusts or similar insects; or if their enemy besiege them within the land, at the gates of their cities, or any affliction or sickness.
> 38Every prayer, every plea that any person will make, [or] by Your people, Yisroel, since every person knows the affliction of his heart; and he will spread out his hands to this Beis Hamikdosh.
> 39May You listen from the heavens, Your Dwelling Place, and forgive and act, and give to each one according to all his ways, for You know his heart; for You alone know the hearts of all the children of men.
> 40That they may fear You all the days that they live on the face of the earth, that You gave to our fathers.
> 41And even to the stranger who is not of Your people Yisroel, and comes from a far off land for the sake of Your Name.
> 42For they will hear about Your great name, and of Your mighty hand and of Your outstretched arm, and they will come to this House and pray.
> 43May You listen from the heavens, Your dwelling place, and do according to all that the stronger calls out to You; so that all the people of the land will know Your Name, to fear You as do Your people, Yisroel, and they will know that your name is called upon this Beis Hamikdosh, that I have built.
> 44When your people go out to war against their enemy, in the manner that you send them, and they will pray to Adonoy by way of the city that You chose, and the house that I built for Your Name.
> 45May You listen from the heavens to their prayers and their pleas, and render their judgement.

The three daily prayers were instituted by the Sages to correspond to the sacrifices, but there always was a biblical commandment to pray, either once daily (according to Maimonides) or in times of trouble (Nachmanides).